# STS/Eclipse: Show Pivotal Server list

Tags: spring-tool-suite

In Eclipse, where do you go in the IDE to display the list of existing Pivotal Servers?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly mean with "existing Pivotal servers". If you refer to Pivotal tc Server instances that you have installed locally in your machine, you can configure them in the "Servers" view. If that is not showing up already, so go "Show View" and select the "Servers" view from that list.

If you refer to instances of Cloud Foundry that you use in the cloud, they can be configured in the "Servers" view, too. To configure a cloud foundry runtime, create a new server in the servers view, select the "Cloud Foundry" type and enter the credentials. Then you have full access to that Cloud Foundry runtime from within STS.

How this helps!!!